# Finding the dim of polynomial subspace $S \in P_n$ s.t $f(0) = f(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$P_n$ is the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq$ n, where $n$ is fixed. Let $S$ denote the set of all polynomials $f$ in $P_n$ satisfying a specified condition. Compute the dimension of $S$.

$f(0) = f(2)$ is the condition that all polynomials in $S$ have. This is a subspace since it closed under the closure axioms. However, I'm not sure how to compute the dim of $S$. I know it's supposed to be $n$. But I don't see why.

My reasoning is this: $f(0) = f(2) = c$, where $c$ is some constant. Doesn't this have dimension 1? So why isn't the dim of $S = 1$ or $n+1$? Since $n=0$, because the constant polynomial has degree 0.

Comment: The map $f \mapsto f(0) - f(2)$ is a linear transformation to $\mathbb R$. It is surjective (take $kx$) hence has rank $1$.  So by rank-nullity its kernel has dimension $dim S - 1$.  The kernel is exactly the $f$'s that you want.

Comment: Is there a different way of doing seeing this?

Comment: perhaps, but you won't find anything faster

Comment: I don't care. I need a different way of understanding why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should write out your thoughts more carefully.  You're making weird jumps in your logic that should fall apart under closer scrutiny

Comment: Like what? Isn't f(0) = f(2) is the constant polynomial? So the subspace we are looking at has degree 0. So it will have  dim = 1.

Comment: $f(0) = f(2)$ means that $f$ admits the same value in the two points $0,2$. This does not mean that the polynomial is constant, neither that anything else is constant. The only thing constant here is $f(0)-f(2) = 0$. For example $(x-1)^2 \in S$ is a non-constant polynomial.

Comment: Here's a way to think about it. An element $f$ of $P_n$ is specified by $n+1$ numbers (namely, the $n+1$ coefficients of the polynomial $f$). The equation $f(0)=f(2)$ is a single homogeneous linear equation satisfied by those $n+1$ coefficients. A single equation in $n+1$ unknowns will have an $n$-dimensional space of solutions.